# Sticky bottom element from router outlet

Tags: css, angular

Structure:

```
<app-header></app-header>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
<app-footer></app-footer>
```

One component has a button I want to make sticky to bottom,. like:

```
position: -webkit-sticky;
position: sticky;
bottom: 1rem;
align-self: flex-end;
```

But you see there is a `app-footer` - my button wont be sticky to bottom when scrolled down in the footer section. How to make it sticky bottom also above the footer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use fixed position for your button

```
.button-class {
 position: fixed;
 bottom: 1rem;
}
```